# Bad EXE format when running an .exe with wine64

Tags: pyinstaller, wine

I created an executable file on my 64-bit Ubuntu machine using pyinstaller and I am trying to run it using wine64. However, I get the error wine: Bad EXE format for chatbot2.exe. I could really use any suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: Is the executable 32-bit? Also, was the executable made for ubuntu and not windows?

Comment: If I type file chatbot2.exe I get: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=..., for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped. The executable was made for Windows.

Comment: Well, it says it was made for Linux.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you so much for answering! Do you happen to know what pyinstaller option I need to add to specify that I want to make the executable for Windows?

Comment: Nope, don't know.

Comment: You have to run pyinstaller on Windows to generate windows executables.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Thank you! I found out in the meantime that I need to use wine on Ubuntu if I want to make a Windows executable. I am now following the steps outlined in https://www.andreafortuna.org/2017/12/27/how-to-cross-compile-a-python-script-into-a-windows-executable-on-linux/ , but I ran into another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68439534/storage-share-mode-not-implemented-when-packaging-a-windows-executable-using-pyi